# Python tkinter image

Tags: python, image, tkinter, encode

Currently, i know 2 ways to display images on Tkinter. First one is to encode the gif image into base64 format and use this

```
myimage=PhotoImage(data="encoded image")
```

It works but the number of code lines it take in my script is way too much especially for a large photo. And If i have multiple images it is quite messy to have the image encoded in the script.

The second way is just to directly point to the location of the image without encoding.But users will most likely be able to see the images in the same directory as the script.

So, i am wondering if there is any other way to display images on tkinter without taking too much code lines yet the users won't be able to see the images in the directory of the script?

Comment: Under windows you can use the different datastreams of your file and write the images to there. `main.py:image1` https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Windows_::DATA_alternate_data_stream This may conflict with coping the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate encoded image data into module.

**Main script**

```
import images
...
myimage1 = PhotoImage(data=images.image1)
myimage2 = PhotoImage(data=images.image2)
...
```

**images.py**

```
image1 = 'encoded image data...'
image2 = 'encoded image data...'
```